# Is it possible to have overlapping views that don't blend?

Tags: swiftui, watchos-6

I'm trying to mimic the grouped Cancel / Set button pair that you see in places like the Stopwatch app. 
I've currently done this by using a `ZStack` with two overlapping `RoundedRectangle` with different `cornerRadius` and `padding`.

This seems to work well shape-wise but there's a subtle colour overlap that I haven't found a way to fix.

[image: This is how it renders]

I've tried playing with `BlendMode` and `opacity' with no luck.

```
Button(action: {}, label: { Text("Cancel").foregroundColor(Color.white) })
.background(VStack(spacing: 0) {
               ZStack {
                   RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:20).foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                   RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).foregroundColor(Color.gray).padding(.leading, 20)
               }})
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've realised that this is actually the button's accent colour being applied. If I set the `accentColour` to `Color.clear`, this overlap disappears.

I actually need this behaviour elsewhere so I've followed [Alejandro Martinez's guide](https://alejandromp.com/blog/2019/06/22/swiftui-reusable-button-style/) on creating reusable Button styles and created this:

```
public struct AccentlessButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    public func body(configuration: Button<Self.Label>, isPressed: Bool) -> some View {
         configuration.accentColor(Color.clear)
    }
}

extension StaticMember where Base: ButtonStyle {
    public static var accentless: AccentlessButtonStyle.Member {
        StaticMember<AccentlessButtonStyle>(AccentlessButtonStyle())
    }
}
```

It seems to inherit the default button styling in all other ways.

Using it requires this:

```
Button(action: {}, label: { Text("Cancel") }).buttonStyle(.accentless)
```